# How to Diagnose the noise from my Hot Water Tank

Tags: hot-water, noise

I Have a air source heat pump supplying a 250L ecoCyl tank.  When it is warming the water, it makes a loud rattling vibrating sound and a series of bangs, getting louder as the tank warms towards 50C.

Is this normal? Should I just put up with it?

Or is there something wrong?

Attached, a clip of the rattling with a bang at 25s.

[audio clip of rattle and bang](https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/kutil/bang-trimmed.m4a)

Comment: I'm honestly not familiar with your style of heating tank, but US water heaters can become noisy if the tank is never drained because sediment in the tank causes uneven heating.  Is it normal to drain your tank regularly to remove sediment?

Comment: the tank is 1 year old and the noises have been ongoing since installation